# Custom action camera sj4000 firmware

Tags: camera, firmware

Is anybody knows if there is custom firmware for sj4000 action cameras? I would like to use camera for timelapse video. There is a setting in Photo Mode that will take a snapshot every 5, 10 or 20 seconds from the time you press the Ok/Record button. But I need at least 60 seconds between the shots. Is anybody tries to hack bin file?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to ask such questions here: http://video.stackexchange.com.

Anyways, as of now there is no custom firmware. Good news: You don't need one. My SJ4000 WiFi has an option "VideoLapse" in the official firmware, where you can choose 1,2,5,10,30 and 60 second intervals. This sounds like exactly what you want.

You may need to upgrade your firmware to make it work (I use G20150408V02). See http://www.sjcam.com/content/category/3-Firmware